# Function create_function() deprecated in cherry plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7.2

I have used cherry plugin in my wordpress site. But for PHP 7.2 ,the create_function() is deprecated.

```
    $conditional_function = create_function('', 'return '.cherry_condition($options_type[$id], 
     $options[$id], $users[$id]).';');
    $conditional_result = $conditional_function();
```

I remplaced with:

```
    $conditional_function = function(){return cherry_condition($options_type[$id], $options[$id], 
    $users[$id]);};

    $conditional_result = $conditional_function();
```

But there are many errors:

```
   Undefined variable: options_type
   Undefined variable: id 
   Undefined variable: options
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is `$conditional_function` set anywhere else, if not then why bother with it and just call the function directly `$conditional_result = cherry_condition($options_type[$id], $options[$id], $users[$id]);`

Comment: If this is a 3rd party plugin, DO NOT UPDATE the plugin with your code. If the developer releases an update all your changes will be lost. It's better to either update the plugin - if there is one - or contact the developer to fix this.